# Defining function for withHandler in Recompose for React

Tags: reactjs, recompose

All of the examples I look at, the function actually called in `withHandlers` seems to call a function from `props`, but I have no idea how that function is defined. Here is a small example from [docs for humans](https://recompose.docsforhumans.com/api/withstate.html).

```
compose(
  withState('count', 'setCount', 0),
  withHandlers({
    incrementCount: props => event => {
      event.preventDefault()
      props.setCount(props.count + 1)
    }
  })
)(ComponentToEnhance)
```

My understanding is this will create a HOC with "state" to track `count`. I would be able to increment the count via an action used the defined handler (e.g. `onClick={incrementCount}`).

My question is then, where is `setCount` actually defined.. I'm imaging something like

```
function setCount(i) {
    return i+1;
}
```

Since it is called from props, do you have to pass it in as props when your using the component? I'm confused why `withState` would need to know the state updater name, or how it is even related if that is the case.

Does it just define a function automatically for you that will replace the state param with whatever argument you pass it (facepalm if so..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`withHandlers` takes a curried / higher order function in order to set the props from other HOC (high order component)'s such as `withSate` or form it's usage.

Enhanced component example:

```
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import React from 'react';

const enhance = compose(
  withState('count', 'setCount', 0),
  withHandlers({
    incrementCount: props => event => {
      // props would contain copy prop. 
      props.setCount(props.count + 1)
    },
    otherExample: () => event => {
      // If you didn't need props in your handler
    },
    otherIncrementCountExample: ({ count, setCount }) => () => {
      // you can exclude event also
      setCount(count + 1);
    }
  });

export default IncButton = ({ count, incrementCount, copy }) => (
  <div>
   <button onClick={incrementCount}> {copy} </button>
  </div>
);
```

Usage:

```
import React from 'react';
import IncButton from './IncButton';
export default App = () => (
  <div>
    <IncButton copy="Increment Me"/>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It is worth noting that the "function" I was referring to in the question (`setCount`) is a setter created by `withState` for the var being created.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the answer, my example here is simpler than my component, but I'll do my best to translate my findings... though this isn't tested below.

```
compose(
  withState('count', 'setCount', 0),
  withHandlers({
    incrementCount: props => event => {
      props.setCount(props.count + 1)
    }
  })
```

(facepalm), it is as I suspected in my question. `withHandlers` just automatically defines a function for you that will replace the state param with whatever argument you pass it. It is not a smart function, though useful. It will take whatever argument you give it, and update your HOC's state with that argument. You'd use it like this...

```
function ComponentToEnhance({someProp="default str", ...props}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.count}</h1>
      <button onClick={props.setCount}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`someProp` is just there to show use of spread operator if you want some props that have a default or get passed in you want to call out specifically...cheers